# Chrome JavaScript setCookie getCookie

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookie

Не удается установить и получить значения cookie в Google Chrom, в других браузерах такой проблемы не наблюдаю.

```
<script>
    document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2021 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";         
    alert(window.document.cookie);
</script>
```

В других браузерах скрипт выполняется корректно. Настройки безопасности в Chrom проверил, запретов или ограничений на использование cookie нет. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А вы покажите, как вы устанавливаете и получаете куки.

Comment: а Вы пытаетесь получить и задать куки для одного и того же источника (сайта) с разных браузеров?

Comment: попытайтесь для начала с консоли браузера записать или считать куки и напишите сюда результат

Comment: куки устанавливаются как: document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2021 12:00:00 UTC; path=/"; а возвращаются при помощи функции alert(window.document.cookie);

Comment: Результат выполнения  document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2021 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
"username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2021 12:00:00 UTC; path=/" Результат выполнения alert(window.document.cookie);
undefined. При этом этот же сценарий в Internet Explorer выполняется корректно. Предполагаю есть нюансы с настройками хрома, но самостоятельно решить проблему не получилос.

Comment: @SergiiGarkusha, если Вам в консоли (при создании кук) вернулся ответ в виде самой куки, значит в браузере всё работает

Comment: @SergiiGarkusha, откройте тогда **DevTools => Application => Storage => Cookies => ДОМЕН_ВАШЕГО_САЙТА** и посмотрите список кук там. если кука там есть, а `document.cookie` он Вам её не показывает, то у меня есть ответ на Ваш вопрос

Comment: В консоли таки да. при этом пустое сообщение Alert не могу объяснить. Более того при считывания куки в функцию getCookie массив значений оказывается пустым function getCookie(name) {
 var cname = name + "=";
 var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
 var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
 for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) 
 {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') 
  {
   c = c.substring(1);
  }
  
  if (c.indexOf(cname) == 0) 
  {
   // alert("Cookie "+window.document.cookie);
   return c.substring(name.length, c.length);

  }

 }
 return "";
}

Comment: В storage cookie нет :(

Comment: могу выложить скрин, только вот вопрос куда ...

Comment: @SergiiGarkusha, залейте изображение на любой хостинг картинок, получите ссылку на Вашу картинку. и вставьте ссылку сюда (прям в комментарий) с помощью вот такой семантики `[КРАТКОЕ_НАЗВАНИЕ_ССЫЛКИ](URL_ССЫЛКИ)`

Comment: [скрин хрома] https://ibb.co/DCCMKD3

Comment: [скрин exlorer] https://ibb.co/jywSvFW

Comment: [скри отладки в хроме] https://ibb.co/pjLJc1v

Comment: @SergiiGarkusha, ответ дал ниже. всегда сразу прикладывайте скрины, чтобы сэкономить время)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а [вот](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues/299#issuecomment-277660471), собственно, и ответ на Ваш вопрос).
если подробнее, то Вы открываете Ваш сайт локально через файловую систему (**file://** протокол). в Хроме так работать не будет. Вам нужно либо использовать какой-то сборщик (аля **Webpack**) где есть `dev-server`, либо развернуть сервер локально, чтобы сайт роздавался с помощью `http` протокола.

Comment: Спасибо большое, т.к. в рунете не нашел объяснения подобного вашему. Теперь все становится на свои места. Еще раз благодарю.